# Exception using @RolesAllowed in SpringBoot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have a basic SpringBoot app. using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
}
```

companyService is injected and not null. Removing `@RolesAllowed` works fine

```
@Autowired
CompanyService companyService;
```

in my applicationConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled=true, securedEnabled=true, prePostEnabled=true)
```

I have a method of a controller anotated like this

```
@ModelAttribute("companies")
    @RolesAllowed({"ROLE_ADMIN"})
    public Iterable<Company> companies(){
        return companyService.findAll();
    }
```

When I try to reach the controller I have an application exception with no information:

```
<div th:utext="'Failed URL: ' +  ${url}"    th:remove="tag">${url}</div>
<div th:utext="'Exception: ' + ${message}"  th:remove="tag">${message}</div>
<div th:utext="'Exception: ' + ${trace}"    th:remove="tag">${trace}</div>


<!--
    Failed URL: null
    Exception: No message available
    Exception: null

    -->
```

Before reaching the controller I check the roles of the user

```
System.out.println("Authorities -> " +
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities())
```

and this is the result:

```
Authorities -> [Authority [authority=ROLE_BASIC], Authority [authority=ROLE_ADMIN]]
```

same result using:

```
  @ModelAttribute("companies")
    @Secured("ADMIN")
    public Iterable<Company> companies(){
        return companyService.findAll();
    }
```

or `@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")`

in the debug:

```
 42410 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@65eab2b2, returned: 1
42410 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful
42410 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
42410 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /company/list reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
42411 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
42411 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
42411 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost] - Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error
```

- companies() is invoked when you remove @Secured, and debugging `AffirmativeBased` I got :

  switch (result) {
              case AccessDecisionVoter.ACCESS_GRANTED:
                  return;
  logger.debug("Authorization successful");

Comment: Is there no stack trace in the log?

Comment: no,  no stack trace in the log

Comment: Does your app ask for user authentication? (i.e. the browser asks for user/password) when you access your secured url?

Comment: yes,  my app ask for user authentication

Comment: Does you have `@EnableWebSecurity` also, and configured `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use either `@Secured` or `@RolesAllowed` use of this annotations is no more recomended. Instead use `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")`

Comment: I got the same error: status=404, error=Not Found   :-(

Comment: Why are  `@RolesAllowed`, `@Secured` no longer recommended? I could not find any reference mentioning that.

Answer (score 0):

is `companies()` invoked when you remove `@Secured` annotation?
if it is, then try to debug 
`org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased`
most likely, at first it will be invoked when checking your url, then it will invoked when you call `companies()` method which is secured by`@Secured` annotation, and for some reason second check fails.

see also:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#authz-pre-invocation